# Removing field via powershell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

A custom solution was installed at one point, and was removed do to it not functioning as expected. after the solution was removed several fields remained, and I'm trying to remove them with the script below.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue"
$w = Get-SPWeb http://spdev1
$f = $w.Fields
$f.Delete("slamidnumber")
$f.Update()
```

When running the script, i'm getting the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop> $f.Delete("slamidnumber")
Exception calling "Delete" with "1" argument(s): "Value does not fall within
the expected range."
At line:1 char:1
+ $f.Delete("slamidnumber")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException
```

I have also tried the following with similar results:

```
PS C:\Users\jwhite\Desktop> $f.Fields("slamidnumber").Delete()
Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldBoolean] doesn't
contain a method named 'Fields'.
At line:1 char:1
+ $f.Fields("slamidnumber").Delete()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

after running the recommended changes, I'm getting the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop> $f.Fields["slamidnumber"].Delete()
An error occurred while enumerating through a collection: Field type
SlamIdField is not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete
this field. .
At line:1 char:1
+ $f.Fields["slamidnumber"].Delete()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Share...on+SPEnumer
ator:SPEnumerator) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadEnumeration
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one...

```
$w = Get-SPWeb http://spdev1
$f = $w.Fields["slamidnumber"]
$f.Sealed = $false
$f.Update()
$f.Delete()
```

Comment: unfortunately the sealed property is not available for object

Answer (score 0):

Use square brackets on the `Fields' property, which hangs off the web variable.

`$w.Fields["slamidnumber"].Delete()`

Comment: you suggestion did resolve my initial error, now i'm running into a new issue (added to my initial post)